# ¿cómo puedo remover este padre de html si presionan este botón jquery(sweetalert)?

Tags: jquery, sweetalert

los que sucede es que necesito remover el padre tr pero solo si pulsan el botón Eliminar en la función ya se elimina de la base de datos si le doy click al botón, pero si meto la linea de remover padre ahí no me lo elimina, también lo intente de la siguiente manera y la variable no cambia de valor, ¿podrían ayudarme a remo-verla solo cuando pulsan el botón eliminar? agradezco su colaboración.

```js
$(".eliminarProducto").click(function () {
        id_producto = $(this).next(".id_producto").val();
        var eliminar = 0;
        swal({
            title: "¿Deseas eliminar el producto?",
            text: "Una vez borrado no podras recuperar el producto",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Eliminar",
            cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: true,
        },
            function (isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    eliminar = 1;
                    swal("Producto eliminado correctamente", "", "success");
                    $.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "index.php",
                        data: { id_producto, funcion: "eliminarProducto" }                        
                    });
                }
            });
        if (eliminar = 1) {
            $(this).parents("tr").remove();
        }


    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (eliminar = 1) {
    $(this).parents("tr").remove();
}
```

En la condicion estas igualando la variable eliminar a 1, deberia ser asi

```
if(eliminar == 1){...}
```